# Solving eqation in Excel

Tags: excel, math

I have problem with creating an eqation in Excel.

Imagine product that is 12 meters long and has 2 prices: P1 and P2. We bought the product for P1 for 1 meter and we want to sell it for P2 for 1 meter. This product will be then cut.
I want to came up with an equation that will allow me to calculate, how many meters (x) sold for P2 will be equal to the rest of 12 meters (12 - x) in P1 price.

```
    (x * P2) - ((12 - x) * P1) = 0
    x * P2 = (12 - x) * P1
    (x * P2) / (12 - x) = P1
    x / (12 - x) = P1 / P2
```

Of course P1 and P2 is known.

Comment: So, first solve math problem by yourself then come up with that solution to here so that visitors can convert that math solution to excel formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple calculation would be:

```
x = (12*P1)/(P1+P2)
```

Excel:

```
=(12*A1)/(A1+A2)
```

Assuming P1 is stored in A1 and P2 is stored in A2

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two tables one for purchase and another for Sold, from there you will caliculate like in the below image.

if you think it is useful to you, kindly reply to me ill share the google sheet link with all formulas, the final output will come automatically when you submit sold data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3w2Z.jpg)